# Connecting to Analysis Services from SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssas

When trying to connect to a SQL Server database, there is an option to connect via SQL Server authentication, but the only option I have with Analysis Services is connecting via Azure Active Directory or Windows Authentication (which I don't think I have).

However, every time I enter in my Microsoft user/password it just keeps prompting for it again and again, going in an infinite loop:

[image]

How do I actually connect to SSAS from SSMS?

Comment: Well, the **Server Name** you've entered appears to be hosted on **Azure** - so if that's the case, you can only use Azure AD credentials to connect to it ....

Comment: Try the Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**

**Authentication type, Active Directory - Universal with MFA support, is recommended.**

Follow the offical document([Manage Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-manage)), it works for me.

[image]

[image]